# Setting content insets on UITextView using XIB

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uiedgeinsets

I have a `UITableViewCell` which contains a `UITextView`.

I'd like to set padding on this text view, so that the cell content is pushed in by 10 on each side.

I understand I can do this in code using         `textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)`

Is this possible using the IB when working with a XIB file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a `Key Path` using a type of Rect.

This should achieve what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: I think this is meant to be a *Size* in IB's User Defined Runtime Attribute.  Rect will technically work but it's internally doing a hard C-style cast from a `CGRect` to `CGSize` (with the `origin` ending up being used as the `CGSize`), so not a good idea.